# USBIP appears to send and receive extra URBs compared to what’s actually being sent by the device

Tags: usb, scapy, hardware-interface, device-emulation

I’ve been playing around with USB emulation with a virtual machine, (specifically with a windows USBIP client and a Scapy server), but when sniffing with USBPCAP and the Loopback adapter for USBIP, I’ve noticed that the exact URBs being sent are not the same.

USBPCAP’s URBs match up to WinAPI’s URB struct while USBIP’s URBs tend to only contain the payload while the rest of the information is sent inside the USBIP protocol.

The weirder thing is that the number of URBs being exchanged are different, with USBIP sending extra GET_CONFIGURATION requests or SET_INTERFACE requests from the host to the usb device.

Is there a way to force usbip to send and receive the exact URBs that the host and device actually use?